# $\int\limits_0^{10}e^{-0.04t}\cdot e^{-0.001t^2}dt$

Tags: integration, error-function

I need to find the following integral

$$\int\limits_0^{10}e^{-0.04t ~-0.001t^2}dt$$
This integral seems to "scream" for the error function, but I have never worked with the error function yet, so I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone please show me how this definite integral can be determined?

**Update:**
After following the hints given, I have the following:

\begin{align}\int\limits_0^{10}e^{\frac{-1}{1000}(t^2+40t)}dt &= e^{\frac{400}{1000}}\int\limits_0^{10} e^{\frac{-1}{1000}(t+20)^2}dt\end{align}

Now, let $u = t+20$, then our integral changes to
\begin{align*}e^{\frac{400}{1000}}\int\limits_{20}^{30}e^{\frac{-1}{1000}u^2}du\end{align*}
I am stuck here though, since I only know how to use the error function of $\int_0^xe^{-at^2}dt$, which is different from what I have, since the lower limit is not zero? Please help!

Comment: Yes it does scream error function. Rewrite the integrand as $exp(-(1/1000)(t^2+40t))$ and complete the square.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - Please check my updated attempt. I seem to be stuck again :(

Comment: Use $\int_0^{30} -\int_0^{20}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - so this equates to \begin{align}e^{\frac{400}{1000}}\left[ \frac{\sqrt{1000\pi}}{2}erf(30) - \frac{\sqrt{1000\pi}}{2}erf(20)\right]\end{align}

Comment: Closer. My erf is a constant that I keep forgetting times $\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$.  We want to make the change of variable $t=u/\sqrt{1000}$, so instead of $30$ at the top end we will have $30/\sqrt{1000}$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  complete the square in the exponent so you get $e^{(a -(b+t)^2)}$ for constants $a,b$.  Pull out the $e^a$ as a multplicative constant. Do a $u$ substitution to make it $e^{-u^2}$ to match the definition of the error function.

Comment: Please check my updated edit. I seem to be stuck again :(